# AngularJS Unit Tests: Injected Services undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have difficulties unit testing angularJS due to the injector not injecting properly. Anything I inject turns out to be `undefined`.

Module:

**app.module.js**

```
angular.module('myServices', []);
```

**AngularTest.js**

```
describe('AngularTest', function() {

    beforeEach(module('myServices'));

    var scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_) {
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        scope = _$rootScope_;

    }));

    describe('Testing Angular injection', function() {

      it('scope should be defined', function() {    
        expect(scope).toBeDefined(); // fails
      });

    });
});
```

I have successfully tested controllers in my main module, however, this particular module is testing my sanity.

Any ideas ?

### EDIT:

**Karma file:**

```
files: [
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/app.module.js',
      'app/components/**/controller/*.js',
      'app/components/**/model/*.js',
      'app/components/**/test/unit/*.js'
    ]
```

The service module is defined in `app.module.js` and the service is at `app/components/services/model/myService.js` (The path seems illogical, I tried to abstract my structure to generalize this question as much as possible)

### EDIT 2:

Karma also seems to not complain: From the log:

```
28 08 2015 03:38:47.095:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
28 08 2015 03:38:47.107:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
28 08 2015 03:38:47.151:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Safari
28 08 2015 03:38:54.790:INFO [Safari 8.0.6 (Mac OS X 10.10.3)]: Connected on socket jhi7nBcWAV_vCJkMAAAA with id 68159057
```

Followed by the failing test case:

```
Safari 8.0.6 (Mac OS X 10.10.3) AngularTest Testing Angular injection scope should be defined FAILED
    /path/to/project/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:32
    forEach@/path/to/project/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:336:24
    loadModules@/path/to/project/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4369:12
    createInjector@/path/to/project/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4294:22
    workFn@/path/to/project/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2390:60
    /path/to/project/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4408:30
    Expected undefined to be defined.
    /path/to/project/app/components/services/test/unit/AngularTest.js:16:34
```

Comment: It should work fine. Are you sure you have loaded the file that has myServices module? What other error it shows

Comment: @PSL Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: Hmm cant say much on this. I cant seem to replicate it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/z0kCoh?p=preview)

Comment: @PSL Huh ? Pulling my hair out over this. Added some Karma output for the failing test, but I don't think it will help...

Comment: Just a long shot, but you might run karma w/the debug log level (you can enable this in the karma config or from the command line: `karma start --log-level debug`. It's pretty verbose, but you might see some warnings/errors that are clues to the problem.

Comment: @SunilD. Exactly what I did just now, still nothing suspicious...

Comment: @PSL Please look at my answer if you are curious what caused the issue... It's ridiculous that the Safari browser does not work correctly with Karma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## DARN YOU SAFARI!

**Solution:** Changed the browser to Chrome in the karma config file and the debug log spat out much more detailed information on what was wrong!

Turned out I did not include needed module dependencies in my karma `files`.

Comment: Same exact problem with Firefox! I wish I can upvote this answer twice!